# Crash and minicrash after fixing several selected errors?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18.2. I intended to fix the invalid features in a polygon layer, therefore I ran the "Check Geometries" and then I selected several errors, maybe tens or hundreds of them, and then I ran "Fix selected errors using default resolution". Very frequently, the qgis creshed and a minicrash report was sent to a folder in C drive.

Could anybody advise me how to stop the qgis from crashing after fixing errors?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an out-of-date mini-version of an out-of-date version of QGIS. [Update to a newer version](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), eg the current 3.6, or the long-term-release 3.4.

If you must use 2.18 for some reason, at least get a newer mini-version of that. 2.18 is no longer maintained, but it was up to at least 2.18.27 before they stopped updating it. 
Old versions of QGIS for Windows are available [here](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/); for all operating systems [here](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis).